# how can I upload my open source software to the ubuntu or other official software source?

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, package, xmake

I want to create my software package and upload the ubuntu or other software sources.

But I don't known how to do it.

My project: https://github.com/waruqi/xmake

please help me, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### General advice

Getting a package included in any distribution is a large task, getting it included in several major ones is going to take a huge amount of time and commitment.

Software goes into distributions by the work of maintainers: someone who likes the program and has the *time*, *skill* and *commitment* to see through its inclusion in the distribution despite any problems that might occur. The work does not stop after the first upload, though. Maintaining a package in a distribution brings with it the obligation to care for the package for the next *few years*: working on bug reports, keeping the packaged version up to date, collaborating with other people to make sure it interacts well with the rest of the distribution, ...

Distributions have very different priorities from you, the author of an individual piece of software. They will expect that you demonstrate some endurance, so they can be reasonably sure that they don't include a package that will be abandoned 5 months down the line. Really think about whether you are prepared to put in the long-term effort before pushing for inclusion of a package! You may be better off just preparing `.deb` and `.rpm` packages that users can manually download and install from your website, at least for the beginning.

#### Technical considerations

As for the technical side, I can't really comment too much on RPM generation, but for Debian packaging, take a look at the [Debian Mentors FAQ](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianMentorsFaq) and the resources linked therein, especially the [New Maintainer's Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/), the [Developer Reference](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/), and the [Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/).

Comment: Thanks very much!  I found homebrew is very well and I can pull request my software to it's github repository.